# Why do I get wildly different answers when computing the mean of a truncated multivariate normal depending on if it is in a for loop or not in R?

Tags: r, truncated-normal-distribution

I wanted to work with the `tmvtnorm` package in R to compute the mean of a truncated multivariate normal. In testing the results from this package, I tried to plot how the mean of one variable changes depending on one of the truncations when I ran across a strange issue: When looping over different truncation values, the results are totally different from when I run the function outside the loop. Is this a problem with the `tmvtnorm` package, or is there something I'm missing about for loops in R? The following code should reproduce my problem:

```
library(tmvtnorm)

#Correlations between variables
rhoYY <- 0.5 

rhoYS <- 0.7071

#Correlation/Covariance matrix. Note there are 3 random variables
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, rhoYY, rhoYS, 
                rhoYY, 1, rhoYS, 
                rhoYS, rhoYS, 1), 3,3)

# Run one truncated normal mean. Get the result of the first variable
testval <- mtmvnorm(sigma = Sigma, lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -0.1), upper = c(-4.0, 0.0, Inf), 
         doComputeVariance = FALSE)$tmean[1]

print(testval)

#Loop over a sequence of upper truncations. Store the mean of the first variable for each

v <- seq(-4, 4, by = 0.01)

ev <- vector(mode = "double", length = length(v))

for(i in v){
  ev[i] <- mtmvnorm(sigma = Sigma, lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -0.1), upper = c(i, 0.5, Inf),
                   doComputeVariance = FALSE)$tmean[1]
}

print(ev[1]) #this should be the same as testval. But it's not. 

#Plotting the results reveals that all the values are wrong and nonsensical. 
plot(v, ev)
```

Comment: The safest way is to use it this way ```for(i in 1:length(v)){
  ev[i] <- mtmvnorm(sigma = Sigma, lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -0.1), upper = c(v[i], 0.5, Inf),
                    doComputeVariance = FALSE)$tmean[1]
}
```

Comment: Wow. Ok, that works. Thanks! I guess I don't really know why looping over the index works but looping over the values doesn't. But I can accept it.

Comment: In your code you were looping $i$ over the values of $v$ but then you used $i$ to  index the elements of $ev$, there was the problem. In what I attached the $i$ is used as index of both $v$ and $ev$